# Image manipulation with Kinect

Tags: kinect, zooming, rotatetransform

I'm trying to create an application that zooms in and out of an image and rotates it via Kinect. So far it works but for either or the cases. What I would like is that if I have rotated the image, that new value is saved for when I zoom, so I zoom on an image that has been rotated X degrees. The way I have it now, if I first rotate and then try to zoom, the image goes back to the initial stage.

```
        private void TrackDistances(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
        if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            ...
            if (wristLeft.Y > shoulderLeft.Y && wristRight.Y > shoulderRight.Y)
            {
                float distance = Math.Abs(wristLeft.X - wristRight.X);
                image_Zoom(distance);
             }

            if (wristLeft.Y < shoulderLeft.Y && wristRight.Y < shoulderRight.Y)
            {
                angleDeg = GetJointAngle(zeroPoint, anglePoint);
                image_Rotate(angleDeg);
            }
        }
    }
    private void image_Zoom(float distance)
    {
        //TransformGroup transformGroup = (TransformGroup)image.RenderTransform;
        //ScaleTransform scale = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];
        //double zoom = distance * 1.5;
        //scale.ScaleX = zoom;
        //scale.ScaleY = zoom;

        double zoom = distance * 1.5;
        double ScaleX = zoom;
        double ScaleY = zoom;
        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(ScaleX, ScaleY);
        image.RenderTransform = scale;
    }

    private void image_Rotate(double angleDeg)
    {
        var angle = angleDeg - 180;
        RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform(angle);
        image.RenderTransform = rotate;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you change RenderTransform to be either ScaleTranform or RotateTransform.
You can set the ScaleTransform and RotateTransform of the image in the XAML, and just change the angle or zoom parameter in the code behind.

also see here:
[How can I do both zoom and rotate on an inkcanvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745438/how-can-i-do-both-zoom-and-rotate-on-an-inkcanvas)